# Accidentally ran command checkout -B "branchname" in git

Tags: git, git-extensions

I needed to commit and push my code. but in git extension, while trying to push the code, i got an error and I accidentally click on a button and my code gone. I went to git extension **log** and check the commands executed. **checkout -B "mybranch"** was executed. Now my whole code is gone. How to get it back?

edit:
my logs after running git reflog
[image]

Comment: Try `git checkout HEAD /your/file/path`

Comment: I had around 10 files within a directory.

Comment: Then try `git reset --hard HEAD`

Comment: Are you missing uncommitted files or whole commits?

Comment: before you do **anything** suggested here, do a copy of your whole folder, incl. `.git`

Comment: The correct response to "I did something and now I don't understand why it is the way it is" is **never** "let me try more random stuff", it is **always** to retract your hands from the keyboard and think. Also, make a backup of your whole directory and experiment on the backup, at least you can't make things worse that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the first step is to relax a bit: *as long as you **did** run `git commit`, your code is not gone!*

What `git checkout -B branchname` does is to ***create or re-set*** the given *branchname*.  Given what else you have mentioned, I believe you actually ran `git checkout -B UIUpdates origin/UIUpdates`, which (for multiple intertwined reasons) ultimately had the effect of doing `git reset --hard UIUpdates`.

Based on what's in your reflog (in the edit):

```
ec1226b HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from UIUpdates to UIUpdates
...
ec1226b HEAD@{5}: branch: Reset to origin/UIUpdates
5fc98bc HEAD@{6}: commit: issues and questions templates.
ec1226b HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from UIUpdates to UIUpdates
ec1226b HEAD@{8}: branch: Reset to origin/UIUpdates
9a4c4ef HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from UIUpdates to UIUpdates
...
```

it looks as though your own commit(s) are probably reachable from hash ID `5fc98bc`.  You can run:

```
git log 5fc98bc
```

to verify that.  If that looks good, you should attach a *new* name to this commit to let you refer to it more easily—and to make sure it stays around longer than the default 30 days that you get to recover from mistakes.

Let's say this is correct (it's the only `commit` line I see in your entire `git reflog` output image *and*, as `HEAD@{6}`, it's immediately followed by a `HEAD@{5}` line written by `git checkout -B`), and you do not currently have a branch named `saveme`, so that this name is available.  You can then run:

```
git branch saveme 5fc98bc
```

to attach the name `saveme` to it.  Now `git log saveme` will show the commit(s), and `git checkout saveme` will get you on a branch that has those commit(s) in it.

---

The key to understanding all of this is to know that in Git, branch *names* are just ways Git has of getting into the *commit graph*.  The names simply record the hash IDs (those incomprehensible strings like `5fc98bc`).  It's the IDs that actually matter; we humans just need *names* for them.

The commit graph represents every commit ever added to your repository, and what Git normally does is *add new commits*.  This is true even when you use apparently-destructive commands like `git reset`.  The commits themselves are *not* destroyed, they just become harder to find.  But branch names also *protect* commits; eventually, if they're "too hard to find", Git will *garbage-collect* them and throw them out for real.  Having a branch (or tag) name that identifies a commit *protects* that commit from this Grim <strike>Reaper</strike> Collector, and also protects all commits *reachable from* that commit.

This is all described quite well at http://think-like-a-git.net/ so you might want to spend some time reading those pages.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** as [@MarcinOrlowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235698/marcin-orlowski) suggested, make a backup including the `.git` folder first.

Since its not only one file as you said in your comment, `git checkout HEAD /your/file/path` wont work. However, you can try

```
git checkout -
```

If that doesn't work try

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: @UmairJameel Try to run `git reflog` and tell me if you see the SHA of your latest commit (`HEAD`)

Comment: @UmairJameel Ok then run `git reset --hard <your sha>`

Comment: what do you mean by <your sha>. is it branch name?

Comment: @UmairJameel No I mean the `SHA` of your **latest commit** you got from the `reflog`

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please check the image i have added?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141557/discussion-between-umair-jameel-and-nulldev).